# How do I let the input types console log what the checked boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, checkbox

I want to let the checked filed console log all their values but it only shows one checked input

I want the console log to only show the value of which radio was checked but it automatically rather shows the value for the first checkbox

This is a fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Nancy4321/hjL3t5qd/

```js
function newForm() {
  var prof = document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=group2]').value
  var edu_level = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox][name=group1]').value;
  var pro_other = document.getElementById('pro_other').value;

  var data = {
    "prof": prof,
    "edu_level": edu_level,
    "pro_other": pro_other,
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="card hoverable">
      <div class="card-content" id="prof">
        <p>Where do you want to go?</p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Gym" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Gym</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Temple" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Temple</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Mars" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Mars</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="space" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Space</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Home" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Home</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Cali" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Cali</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Tulsa" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Tulsa</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="specify" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Other:<input id="pro_other" type="text" placeholder="Please Specify Here"></span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card hoverable">
      <div class="card-content" id="edu_level">
        <p>Highest Level of Education </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Tertiary" class="with-gap" name="group2" type="radio" />
            <span>Tertiary</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Secondary" class="with-gap" name="group2" type="radio" />
            <span>Secondary</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Junior Secondary" class="with-gap" name="group2" type="radio" />
            <span>Junior Secondary</span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="action" onclick="newForm()">Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=group2]:checked').value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this - you need to iterate the checkboxes

Here I get the values of the checked elements

Note I gave the form an ID and removed the inline button click

```js
document.getElementById("newform").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove when tested

  const prof = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name=group2]:checked')].map(elem => elem.value)
  const edu_level = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox][name=group1]:checked').value;
  const pro_other = document.getElementById('pro_other').value;

  var data = {
    "prof": prof,
    "edu_level": edu_level,
    "pro_other": pro_other
  }
  console.log(data);
  
})
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="newform">
    <div class="card hoverable">
      <div class="card-content" id="prof">
        <p>Where do you want to go?</p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Gym" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Gym</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Temple" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Temple</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Mars" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Mars</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="space" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Space</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Home" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Home</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Cali" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Cali</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Tulsa" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Tulsa</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="specify" type="checkbox" name="group1" />
            <span>Other:<input id="pro_other" type="text" placeholder="Please Specify Here"></span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card hoverable">
      <div class="card-content" id="edu_level">
        <p>Highest Level of Education </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Tertiary" class="with-gap" name="group2" type="radio" />
            <span>Tertiary</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Secondary" class="with-gap" name="group2" type="radio" />
            <span>Secondary</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input value="Junior Secondary" class="with-gap" name="group2" type="radio" />
            <span>Junior Secondary</span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="action">Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only selects the first element. To do what you want, you will need to use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all the inputs, and get their value with the loop.

Or use `document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=group2]:checked')` to select only checked inputs on the page. You can read more about :checked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).